# Play music in background after killing the app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How can I implement this functionality? I need to play music in background even after killing the app or we can after removing the from recently use.

I tried changes in the main file according to a video

```
import 'package:just_audio_background/just_audio_background.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Home.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await JustAudioBackground.init(
    androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.ryanheise.bg_demo.channel.audio',
    androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
    androidNotificationOngoing: true,
  );
  runApp(Home());
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove audioplayer.dispose() wherever implemented.
2. Checkout didChangeAppLifecycleState implementation which allows you to control the app in inactive, paused, resumed states